# Using bash, how would I add specific text every so many characters in a text file?

Tags: bash

I have a text file that I need to add $LINE followed by a page break. So for example, in a text file of

> This is a random text file that I have sitting here and I'm just writing to fill space for the sake of this example. The content of this text is irrelevant and only goes to demonstrate the meaning of the question that I'm asking. Once more, I'm just writing to fill space.

I want to turn that into

> $LINE This is a random text file that I have sitting here and I'm just writing to fill space for the sake of this example.
>
> $LINE The content of this text is irrelevant
>
> $LINE and only goes to demonstrate the meaning of the question that I'm asking.
>
> $LINE Once more, I'm just writing to fill space.

Given that each $LINE is followed by exactly 175 characters of text before breaking off to the next $LINE, what would be the best way to split the entire text file in the manner I've described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to correctly handle files with NUL characters, you can use `read` to collect each segment into a buffer, and then `printf` to emit both that buffer and the characters being added:

```
size=175                  # number of bytes per section; tune to fit
interspaced_char=$'\n\n'  # character(s) to intersperse; likewise

while REPLY=; IFS= read -r -d '' -n "$size" || [[ $REPLY ]]; do
  printf '%s' "$REPLY"
  (( ${#REPLY} == $size )) && printf '%s' "$interspaced_char"
done <input >output
```

Allowing the loop to proceed when `read` returns a nonzero exit status but `$REPLY` is non-empty after its execution permits partial reads at the end of the input file.

If you *do* need to handle NUL characters, your better bet is to use a programming language with Pascal-style strings (such as Python) rather than NUL-terminated strings (as used by bash); representing strings containing NULs is possible in bash (by use of arrays), but this adds very nontrivial complexity.

Comment: Charles, why `-d` and empty-string with `-n` and not just `-N`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, in short, laziness -- sticking with the options whose semantics I know well.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{175\}\)/\1\n\n/g' /path/do/file.txt > /path/do/new_file.txt
```

Comment: Just FYI; This is non-portable.  It will work with GNU sed, but not most other versions, although assuming you are on Linux, that probably doesn't matter.  Adding newlines with non-GNU sed is very difficult, so I have still given you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of excellent solutions offered. One additional consideration is whether you want the break to occur on a word-boundary (at the end of the word) or just split any word in two pieces when the break occurs on the exact character. Following on the `sed` solution by Deep, here is a small addition that causes the break to occur at the end of the current word. In general this will add between 0-10 additional chars:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{175\}[^ ]*\s\)/\1\n/g' /path/do/file.txt > /path/do/new_file.txt
```

Sometimes whole words are desirable. (double-spacing also removed. if desired, just add and additional `\n` to the one in the expression)